How to show dashed Y-axis, center X-ticks, and hide X-grid in Vue-Chartjs?
I need a horizontal dashed line, no y-axis ticks, hidden x-axis grid lines, and centered x-axis ticks for my bar chart. Solution required in vue-chartjs.
Chartjs installed package:
"chart.js": "^4.4.3",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
Here is the simplest solution of this problem.


Here is the simplest solution of this problem.
option object is here:-
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        backgroundColor: "#227799",
        yAlign: "center",
      },
      datalabels: {
        // Position of the labels
        // (start, end, center, etc.)
        anchor: "end",
        offset: -7, // adjust this value to move the label closer to the bar
        // Alignment of the labels
        // (start, end, center, etc.)
        align: "end",
        // Color of the labels
        color: "#3c0d48",
        font: {
          weight: "bold",
        },
        formatter: function (value, context) {
          // Display the actual data value
          return value > 0 ? value : ""; // only display value if it's greater than 0
        },
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          minor: {
            enabled: true, // show minor ticks
            display: "auto", // display minor ticks automatically
            color: "gray", // color of minor ticks
            lineWidth: 0.5, // width of minor ticks
          },
        },
        grid: {
          drawTicks: true,
          display: true,
          offset: false,
          tickColor: "#707070",
          color: "transparent",
        },
        border: {
          display: true,
          color: "#707070",
        },
        ticks: { color: "#000" },
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          color: "#707070",
          tickBorderDash: [],
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true, // <-- this removes x-axis line
          lineWidth: 0.5,
          drawTicks: false,
        },
        border: {
          display: false,
          dash: [4, 4],
        },
        ticks: {
          color: "#00000",
          display: true,
          padding: 8,
        },
      },
    },
  },

Please share solution if you have.
Thanks
